# jQuery Scroll to Sections according to the index of the section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I hope I explain this well enough for an answer.

I have created a side navigation for a page, and created a simple jQuery script to dynamically add buttons based on the number of section's on the page, this works well.

So what I want to do is, when the a link on the nav is clicked it corresponds to the index of the section and scrolls to that.

For example if the second link is clicked it goes to section 2.

It's late and i'm probably missing something, but just can't seem to pass the index of the button (list item) to the index of the section.

I might be miles off, so be gentle, first time I have tried anything like this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var $section = $('section').length;
var $nav = $('.side-navigation li').length;
//************************************************************************************//
//Dynamically add navigation buttons to side navigation dependant on number of sections
//************************************************************************************//
for(var i=0; i <= $section; i++);
$('section').each(function() {
    $('.side-navigation').append('<li><a href="#"></a></li>');
});
//************************************************************************************//
//Scrolls to section corresponding with the index of the link
//************************************************************************************//
$('.side-navigation li').click(function(){
        var index = $('.side-navigation li').index(this);
        console.log('this is index number' + " " + index);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('section[i]').offset().top
        })
    });
//************************************************************************************//
//End
//************************************************************************************//
```

});

Comment: Just in case, take a look at [pagePilign.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/) see it in action in Facebook Groups: http://www.facebookgroups.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have now worked it out, may not be the most elegant but gives me something to work on:

Here is my current solution:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var $section = $('section').length;
var $nav = $('.side-navigation li').length;
//************************************************************************************//
//Dynamically add navigation buttons to side navigation dependant on number of sections
//************************************************************************************//
$('section').each(function() {
    $('.side-navigation').append('<li><a href="#"></a></li>');
});
//**************************************************************************
//Dynamically add a unique class for each section for nav to target
//**************************************************************************
$('section').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('section' + (i));
});
//************************************************************************************//
//Scrolls to section corresponding with the index of the link
//************************************************************************************//
$('.side-navigation li').click(function(){
        var index = $('.side-navigation li').index(this);
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.section' + (index)).offset().top})
    });
//************************************************************************************//
//End
//************************************************************************************//
});
```